# Opening System Application Using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, system, implicit

I am trying to make a simple application which will send the user to a specific (system installed) app (system settings, calendar, browser, etc.) when clicked by the user from the home screen or app drawer.

For instance, I am currently trying to open the system settings whenever my app is launched, just like a shortcut for settings does.

Is it possible to implement this the way I want it? Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void  LaunchComponent (String packageName, String name){
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
        i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.sec.android.app.controlpanel");
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

I currently do not have a layout file, such as main.xml, in my app, as it doesn't have any UI or layout elements. All it should do is send the user to another app activity. I have been using this tutorial (missing link) and I've implemented all the code examples and I cannot figure it out, I am new to android development and java is not my best language. Open to any criticism or suggestions.

Comment: what's the problem exactly? as above code is not complete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make the call to LaunchComponent which can be done in onCreate first life-cycle callback function

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     LaunchComponent (packageName, name);
}
```

updated

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         LaunchComponent ("com.sec.android.app.controlpanel", "abc?");
    }


public void  LaunchComponent (String packageName, String name){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

Comment: Yeah im still having problems, in Eclipse the launch component, wants it to be void, and i cant see to figure out how to set the package i want, would i be replacement packageName with com.xxx.xxx.xx or would i make a string that name is packageName with the value of com.xxx.xxx.xxx, Also my public case is MainActivity extends Activity {       is the right public class to use

Comment: from where you will get package name 'com.xxx.xxx.xxx' ?

Comment: the abc?, what is that referring too? Also do i need to make a string for the package name or anything special in the manifest

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
 E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

Comment: 2nd part.E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: 3rd  E/AndroidRuntime(281): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.contacts/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)

Comment: as the above "have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

Comment: I have ised your method and it  for launching a application kike contacts. Im trykng to launch a activity,  the app on my phone in trykng to launch dkesnt have a icon or launch activity,  it has activiry but yoi have ti open the recent apps to grt to my task manager,  therefir im tring ri launch a direct actvity i know of,  hiw can i di that,  this methid about doesnt work .

Answer (score 1):

In this example you can open system alarm clock app., hope it helps, example activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
        if (packageManager != null) {

            Intent AlarmClockIntent = 
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(
                        Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER).setComponent(
                                new ComponentName("com.android.deskclock", "com.android.deskclock.DeskClock"));

            ResolveInfo resolved = packageManager.resolveActivity(AlarmClockIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            if (resolved != null) {
                startActivity(AlarmClockIntent);
                finish();
                return;
            } else {
                // required activity can not be located!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may help, sorry (New Developer) where would i input this into the above code, after the onCreate?? or after the recommended above LaunchComponent

Comment: You can insert it in onCreate(), or better in onResume() - without problem

Comment: I hate to continue to ask you guys for support, i feel really stupid. Hopefully eventually this stuff will click, Could you provide a exampe of the full java file

Comment: Also what would the manifest look like, im assuming just a basic intent filter for action main and category launcher . right?

Comment: Please look above in updated answer, and yes only basic intent filter for action main and category launcher is needed for manifest

Comment: public class TestActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
  if (packageManager == null) {

   Intent AlarmClockIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
     .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
     .setComponent(
       new ComponentName("com.android.contacts",
         "com.android.contacts.DialContactsEntryActivity"));
   startActivity(AlarmClockIntent);

   // close your activity
   finish();
  }
 }
}`

Comment: Yeah just getting a White blank screen, i change the package to something basic that most device would have and thats the contact package. com.android.contacts

Comment: If you could take a log at my code, sorry to bug you so much Gordon, I highly appreciate you taking the time to help me. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/68717396/TestActivity.zip

Comment: @Jaison - Please take a look in update source in my answer, I have cleared all except example activity that can Help you. And please use provided 'DeskClock' for testing - I have tested this code in 4.0 emulator with your project and it works!.