# Opening Android system apps/utilities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am learning Android. I learned to use my app to start another app I wrote. Using this code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button appOpener = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    appOpener.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            PackageManager firstApp = getPackageManager();
            i = firstApp.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.assignment.projecttomiko");
        }
    });
}
```

It's pretty straight-forward and I am happy wit it. But now I want to start apps already on the Android platform itself, like browser, calender, calculator, etc. From the above, I see I just have to put in the package name of my other apps. I am assuming I can do the same thing to say start a calculator. Or maybe not. What is the best way to do this? If I can use package names, then what are the package names of these in-built apps. If there's a better way I would like someone to help me out.

I read this: [Opening System Application Using Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268060/opening-system-application-using-intent) and realised there's an introduction of an extra `LaunchComponent` I don't know what that is but the main thing is I see on that thread that they are also putting in some package names to call system apps. What'll be your best way to get this done? :)

EDIT:
I searched for hours and tried this code but doesn't work :(

```
// activity name and package for stock calculator
 private static final String CALCULATOR_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.android.calculator2";
 private static final String CALCULATOR_CLASS_NAME = "com.android.calculator2.Calculator";


    public void launchCalculator() {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(CALCULATOR_PACKAGE_NAME,
                CALCULATOR_CLASS_NAME));
        try {
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException noSuchActivity) {
            // handle exception where calculator intent filter is not registered
        }
    }
```

Comment: It isn't usual to start 3rd party apps using the package name - that  includes those provided by the device manufacturer. What you have to remember is Android is an open-source OS and each manufacturer is able (up to a point) to implement functionality as they choose. Consequently the different manufacturers can implement their own calenders, calculators etc etc using their own corporate package names. The normal way to do things is to use generic 'actions' such as `ACTION_VIEW` (for example) or to use Content Providers to access other apps.