# Launch System Apps by their Package Names in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on an App which launches App by getting its package Name, So the installed Apps are working fine but System Apps which the device already have are not opening at all, please guide me that how to resolve this issue, My code is:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package_name_here");
```

In case of opening system Apps by their package names **LaunchIntent** returned null, So this is the problem please guide me, i will be very thankful to you

Comment: can you give a concretely reproducible example?

Comment: if the package does not contain a main Leanback activity, this method returns null. So check if the system app you are trying to launch has one or not ?

Comment: Refer this link ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268060/opening-system-application-using-intent